# JDBC throws MySQL syntax Exception, despite valid query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hello helpful folks,

I've a small part in an application which creates a new db schema based on a mysqldump.
The relevant part looks like this:

```java
log.info("= setup basic database");
// Execute each command in the dump
for (String query : dump.split(";")) {
    statement.execute(query);
}
```

This works fine but some statements just break with something like

```java
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ot_subtotal.php' at line 1
```

The query in this case is

```java
INSERT INTO `configuration` VALUES (194,'MODULE_ORDER_TOTAL_INSTALLED','ot_subtotal.php;ot_discount.php;ot_coupon.php;ot_shipping.php;ot_cod_fee.php;ot_gv.php;ot_subtotal_no_tax.php;ot_tax.php;ot_total_netto.php;ot_total.php',6,0,NULL,'2016-06-17 15:27:24',NULL,NULL);
```

If I replace the string "'ot_subtotal.php;ot_discount.php;ot_coupon.php;ot_shipping.php;ot_cod_fee.php;ot_gv.php;ot_subtotal_no_tax.php;ot_tax.php;ot_total_netto.php;ot_total.php'" with something like "hello world" it works and breaks at a another query later on.

The thing is, I'm able to import the dump via the terminal command "mysql ... < dump.sql" without a problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of

```
for (String query : dump.split(";")) {
    statement.execute(query);
}
```

You are splitting at `;` which result in incomplete queries.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO `configuration` VALUES (194,'MODULE_ORDER_TOTAL_INSTALLED','ot_subtotal.php;ot_discount.php;ot_coupon.php;ot_shipping.php;ot_cod_fee.php;ot_gv.php;ot_subtotal_no_tax.php;ot_tax.php;ot_total_netto.php;ot_total.php',6,0,NULL,'2016-06-17 15:27:24',NULL,NULL);
```

Above query after split at `;` will be

```
INSERT INTO `configuration` VALUES (194,'MODULE_ORDER_TOTAL_INSTALLED','ot_subtotal.php
```

Which is incorrect.

Comment: Ouch, so obvious. Thanks for the quick help =)

Comment: Glad that helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
dump.split(";")
```

Use

```
dump.split(";\n")
```

If you created the dump file in normal way.